# Why am i having an error when i move my nextjs app to production?

Tags: next.js, production-environment, server-error

I have a nextjs app. Everything works fine in development mode. I moved it to vercel temporarily and it was still working. Then I hosted it on `Smartasp.NET` server and I started having some errors.

The images were not loading (not the real problem)
When I click on a link on the header, sometimes it goes, then sometimes I got this error

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)
```

and if I reload the page, the error changes to this

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

and when I check the console, I get this error

```
TypeError: a[e] is not a function
```

I have tried getting understanding what is causing the error but i can't find anything. Please I'll be grateful if someone can help. Thank you

I was expecting it to work fine since it worked fine on development